# In Excel, need to match the numbers in each row and add the number of cells containing the match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]
In Excel I am trying to match the numbers in a list to the numbers in another list on the same worksheet, then count how many cells contain the matched numbers.

Column A is a list of names. Column B thru F is the numbers assigned to each name (the master list). Columns I thru N have numbers entered (the entry list). I need see how many cells in each row of the master list match all of the cells in the entry list (several rows).

For example, on the master list is John, he has 2 numbers in cells B2 thru F2 that match the cells in columns I thru N. So the result (2) is displayed in G2. Please help!

I have tried countif in conditional formatting, and am able to highlight the matched cells in color, but I don't know how to add the number of cells containing the matched numbers.

```
=countif($H:$N,B2)>0
```

Comment: Do you need to check each individual number of the master list with each individual number of the entry list?  (eg. say B2 = 1, H2=1, I2 =1, J2=1; this would return 3)

Comment: This can be easily done with vba code I just need more specifics on what you need

Comment: Hi Jane, I have included an image of a sample. Yes each individual number in the master list needs to be compared with each number in the entry list. The entry list will have many rows of numbers to compare from. And the master list needs a count for each name on the list (count per row) that match any of the numbers in the entry list. I hope that makes sense! Thank you!!

Comment: I did try the following function in VBA, but it only works for one row, and there will be many rows in the master list.

Comment: Public Sub CountColorCells()
        'Variable declaration
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim lColorCounter As Long
        Dim rngCell As Range
        'Set the range
        Set rng = Sheet1.Range("B2:K2")
        'loop through each cell in the range
        For Each rngCell In rng

Comment: 'Checking Green color
        If Cells(rngCell.Row, rngCell.Column).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = _
                                                       RGB(169, 208, 142) Then
            lColorCounter = lColorCounter + 1
        End If
    Next
    'Display the value in cell L2

Comment: One more question, do you want the number of matches for B2 to be stored in its own cell or do you want the total # of matches for cells B2:F2 to be stored in a single cell?

Comment: Sorry for the delay...Add all of b2 thru f2 and put the total into g2. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can also put the Countif's together in a single formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(I:N,B2:F2))
```

or if there is a possibility of duplicates in columns I:N and you only want to count them once,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF(I:N,B2:F2)>0))
```

[image]

Here is an example of the second formula counting only distinct occurrences

[image]

Comment: Hello thank you. I tried this and it highlights starting with the b2 cell, even if that isn't  the cell with the matching number. And how do I get this to add all the highlighted cells from the row? Thank you!

Comment: (and place the total of each row into G2?)

Comment: (I entered this into CF, I'm not sure if that was correct to do, but when I enter into G2 it doesn't work)

Comment: Your countif is fine for individual cells, the idea was that my formula would go in G2 to get the total as in your comment. I don't know why it doesn't work for you, is there any error message or just a count of zero?

Comment: Have added screenshot to illustrate formula working in G2. The second formula is in H2, but you only need it if you want to exclude duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub macro()

Dim lastRow As Long, count As Long

lastRow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlup).Row

count = 0
For xrow = 2 To lastRow
    For xcol = 2 To 6
        For i = 9 To 14
            If Cells(xrow, xcol) = Cells(xrow, i) Then
                count = count + 1
            Else:
            End If
        Next i
    Next xcol
Cells(xrow, 7).Value = count
count = 0
Next xrow

End Sub
```

### EDIT:

Changed the `Cells(i, xcol)` in the `if` statement to `Cells(xrow, i)` and it fixed it.  Works on my machine.

Comment: Thank you for the Macro. It doesn't work, yet, but I am trying to manipulate the code to make it work. Thank you!

Comment: Just fixed it.  Try it now